# Sample Spark Program

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, bigdata

Hi I'm learning Spark and Scala I have one scenario where I need to come up with Sparkscala code

Input File

```
Name  attr1 attr2 attr3  
John    Y     N    N  
Smith   N     Y    N
```

Expected Output

```
John  attr1 Y  
John  attr2 N  
John  attr3 N  
Smith attr1 N  
...  
...
```

I know how to do this in Map-Reduce

For each line get the Name sepearately and iterate through the attr values and emmit the output as `(Name, attrX Y/N)` but in scala and Spark it is bit confusing, can any one help me?

Comment: Outside of Spark, read the first line, extract the list of attrN , Now using Spark, set that as a broadcast variable to make it accessible to the workers. Make an RDD out of the rest of the file. flatMap over the RDD producing the entries for a given row. And you're done.

Comment: Also, I think your  example is wrong. "Smith attr2 N"  should either be "Smith attr1 N" or Smith attr2 Y"

Answer (score 2):

Assume that you already know the number of input attributes, and input attributes are separated by `\t`, then you could do this:

**In Java**

```
// load data file
JavaRDD<String> file = jsc.textFile(path);

// build header rdd
JavaRDD<String> header = jsc.parallelize(Arrays.asList(file.first()));

// subtract header to have real data
JavaRDD<String> data = file.subtract(header);

// create row rdd
JavaRDD<Row> rowRDD = data.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String,Row>(){
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public Iterable<Row> call(String line) throws Exception {
        String[] strs = line.split("\t");
        Row r1 = RowFactory.create(strs[0], "Attr1", strs[1]);
        Row r2 = RowFactory.create(strs[0], "Attr2", strs[2]);
        Row r3 = RowFactory.create(strs[0], "Attr3", strs[3]);
        return Arrays.asList(r1,r2,r3);
    }
});

// schema for df
StructType schema = new StructType().add("Name", DataTypes.StringType)
                                    .add("Attr", DataTypes.StringType)
                                    .add("Value", DataTypes.StringType);

DataFrame df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rowRDD, schema);
df.show();
```

**Here is the output:**

```
+-----+-----+-----+
| Name| Attr|Value|
+-----+-----+-----+
|Smith|Attr1|    N|
|Smith|Attr2|    Y|
|Smith|Attr3|    N|
| John|Attr1|    Y|
| John|Attr2|    N|
| John|Attr3|    N|
+-----+-----+-----+
```

Scala and Java are similar, you could easily translate those into Scala.